# Prove that $ (n,m)=2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{i m}{n}\right]+n+m - n m. $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Prove  that

$$
(n,m)=2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{i\,  m}{n}\right]+n+m - n\,  m.
$$

Comment: We can try to think with the index $i$. In the case of $n>m$. Which $i$ gives $n<im$, and we will get an easier floor function

Comment: Maybe we can the $\tau$ function with the numbers of divisors of $im$...

Comment: It's also know as Polezzi's theorem. Here is the reference https://books.google.fr/books?id=-9pg-4Pa19IC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=polezzi+theorem&source=bl&ots=At0PSpvApS&sig=L25JfsdASSzTwn2-WmaU4y2gJrQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwy9GhkffQAhVCsBQKHZjyChEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=polezzi%20theorem&f=false

Comment: well, it is the Hacks' formula, 1891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look first at the following sum :
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]\implies S=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{(n-i) m}{n}\right]$$
So we will have :
$$\begin{align*}
2S &=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]+\left[ \frac{(n-i) m}{n}\right]\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(m+\left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]+\left[ -\frac{i m}{n}\right]\right)\\
&=m(n-1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]+\left[ -\frac{i m}{n}\right]\right)\end{align*}$$

But we know that:
${\displaystyle \left[ x\right] +\left[ -x\right] =0 \mbox{ if }}x\in \mathbb {Z}$ and $-1{\mbox{ if }}x\not \in \mathbb {Z}  $,This terminates the proof by noticing that $\frac{i\,m}{n}$ is an integer iff $i$ is divisible by $\frac{n}{(n,m)}$ and there are exactly $(n,m)$ divisors of this number in the range $[1,n]$ :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]+\left[ -\frac{i m}{n}\right]\right)=-n+\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,\frac{i\,m}{n}\in \mathbb{Z}}1=-n+(n,m)$$

Finally:

> $$2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{i\,m}{n}\right]=m(n-1)-n+(n,m) $$

Comment: Could you re-explain the part with $i$ and $(n,m)$ please ?

Comment: let's take $\alpha=n/m$ hence you can see that the sum to evaluate is $\sum_{i=1}^n (\left[ i\,\alpha\right] +\left[ -i\,\alpha\right])=(\left[ \alpha\right] +\left[ -\alpha\right])+(\left[ 2\,\alpha\right] +\left[ -2\,\alpha\right])+(\left[ 3\,\alpha\right] +\left[ -3\,\alpha\right])+\cdots$. Now  all these terms are either $-1$ or $0$ you just need to find which ones are equal to $-1$ or which ones are equal to $0$, the term $(\left[ i\,\alpha\right] +\left[ -i\,\alpha\right])$ is equal to zero if an only if $i\alpha$ is an integer which is equivalent to $i$ is a multiple of $n/(n,m)$

Comment: Ok thank you, but you meant $\alpha=m/n$ right ?

Comment: Yes $\alpha=m/n$ , sorry my mistake